# Finding server password encryption properties

Tags: sap-ase

1> how can i find whether server is accepting encrypted password or not from C program using sybase library(encryption set by sp_configure "net password enryption reqd",1), to make sure whether i should call function ct_con_props (CS_SEC_EXTENDED_ENCRYPTION) or not

Comment: Please review the answers and progress the question.

Answer (score 1):

`master.. sysconfigures` contains one row for every configuration parm, with its default values.

`master.. syscurconfigs` contains one row for every configuration parm that has been set on your server, and their runtime values.

Therefore:

```
SELECT ISNULL(value, 0)
    FROM  master.. syscurconfigs
    WHERE comment = "net password encryption reqd"
```

If it is 1 then it is set, otherwise it is not (default, 0)